# Match only if all elements of a column are in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've made a little database in SQL that as 2 tables `Product` (`Name`, `Ingredient` and `Available` (`Ingredient`):

```
|     Product         | Available  |
|  Name  | Ingredient | Ingredient |
|   1    |      a     |      a     |
|   1    |      b     |      c     |
|   2    |      a     |
|   2    |      c     |
```

I want the name of a product only if ALL its ingredients are inside the `Available` table.
For the previous example, the result should be: `Product` "2"
and not `Product` "1", because I don't have the ingredient "b" in the `Available` table.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `left join` (to figure out which `Products` don't have necessary `Ingredients`) and `group by` + `having` to filter `Products` that have at least one missing `Ingredient`:

```
select p.Name 
from Products p 
left join Available a on a.Ingredient = p.Ingredient
group by p.Name
having sum(a.Ingredient is null) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this also:

```
WITH TEMP_PRODUCTS AS
(
    SELECT NAME, COUNT(1) AS NUMBER_OF_INGREDIENTS
      FROM PRODUCT
  GROUP BY PRODUCT
)
SELECT PRD.NAME, COUNT(1) AS NUMBER_OF_AVAILABLE_INGREDIENTS
  FROM PRODUCT PRD
  JOIN TEMP_PRODUCTS TMP ON PRD.NAME = TMP.NAME
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM INGREDIENT ING
                WHERE ING.INGREDIENT = PRD.INGREDIENT)
 GROUP BY PRD.NAME
 HAVING COUNT(1) = TMP.NUMBER_OF_INGREDIENTS;
```